# Removing .html & .php from URL

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, url-rewriting, godaddy, clean-urls

I have searched religiously through the web to find an answer to this quest.

I don't know thing about .htaccess or web.config.

I'm currently hosting my website through GoDaddy.com. From what ive been able to uncover is that GoDaddy uses a windows based server so the .htaccess wont work, hince why i tried using web.config.

I have tried creating a .htaccess and a web.config file and uploading them in the same place as my index.html.

Could someone please help me.

Comment: "GoDaddy uses a windows based server" - GoDaddy offers both Linux and Windows hosting, so you need to find out what _you_ are using!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is the hosting im working with Operating System
WINDOWS
PHP Version
5
IIS Version
IIS 7.0
.NET Version
ASP.Net 2.0/3.0/3.5